# Data organization for a simple pie chart with changing data based on a <select>

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm just getting started with d3.js, and so far am quite impressed, both at the library and at my trying to learn this while sick with a bad flu.

I'm having trouble getting my head wrapped around the best way to organize data.  Each example I can find on simple pie charts has a slightly different structure to its data.  What I am wanting to do I thought would be very simple.  I'll list all my goals here, although the primary question remains one of data organization.

I have two sets of data, one is a world-id to world-name mapping:

```
{ "0": "Worldwide", "104": "Antonia Bayle", "312": "Harla Dar" }
```

the other dataset consists of some data about these, in this case deity worship for each server, a bit of which looks like:

```
{
  "312": {
    "Bristlebane":199,
    "Solusek Ro":160,
    "The Tribunal":144,
    "Rallos Zek":143,
    "Karana":75,
    "Tunare":68,
    "Rodcet Nife":56,
    "Innoruuk":43,
    "Bertoxxulous":40,
    "Mithaniel Marr":36,
    "Anashti Sul":32,
    "Brell Serilis":31,
    "Cazic-Thule":28,
    "Quellious":12
  }, "0": {
    "Bristlebane":12505,
    "Solusek Ro":12193,
    "Rallos Zek":7718,
    "Tunare":7135,
    "Mithaniel Marr":5950,
    "Karana":5456,
    "Anashti Sul":5083,
    "The Tribunal":4851,
    "Bertoxxulous":4203,
    "Rodcet Nife":3684,
    "Innoruuk":3430,
    "Quellious":2211,
    "Brell Serilis":1782,
    "Cazic-Thule":1569
  } ...
```

What I would like to do is list the world names in a `<select>`, and when that one is selected, a pie chart (donut more likely) is rendered for that selection.  I would also like to label the pieces, but that may be another question, later.  :)

I can see some utility in converting the format into something like:

```
{
  "0": {
    label: "Worldwide",
    values: [
      { label: "Bristlebane", value: 12505},
      {...},
    ]
  }
}
```

but would appreciate advice on what is "easiest" for d3 to use, so I won't be fighting the system.

Comment: It looks like you should be able to use the data format you have without any modifications. The data you would select already gives you everything you need for a pie chart.

Comment: Then it's just a matter of teaching d3 how to consume that format.  I'll see if I can get it going and update the question if (when) I have problems.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you want to use with this.

Comment: It would help if I had code.  :)  Right now, I'm still trying to learn if there are conventions of data formatting that can help make my life easier later.

Comment: Well, you could structure your data exactly as in one of the examples you've found, but apart from that there's no general guidelines.

Comment: That's what I'm learning.  A bit of commonality between the different examples would be good, because each one constructs its data differently.  I was just wondering if there was a "best" organization for the data as I presented to make it easier.  I understand anything can work, but I'm seeking a "work without a lot of trickery" recommendation.  As it appears that is not available, I'll cope.

Comment: This depends entirely on your application. If one of the examples is exactly like what you're looking for, use that data format.